# How to disable tabs on windows 10 login

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

I have a magswipe card I want to use to log in to my computer (school ID). I want to use this as a password, with the card reader plugged in as a keyboard. The only problem is that this particular ID contains a tab, which removes the cursor from the login box. I thought I could run a program before login and use that to trigger the application "Simple Disable Key," but I discovered things like that only run once you've logged in successfully and the desktop loads. Is there any way to work around the tab, or should I just give up on using this card?

Comment: Could you give more information in the post about this supposed smart card? I was not able to find out anything about the specific card, nor was it clear what you are describing by "tab" or what you are trying to accomplish from running this program before even logging on.

Comment: And please fix the question title which doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is not a smart card, it is a school id with a magstrip, just like a credit card or gift card. I have a reader for this type of card, which acts just like a keyboard. I want to use this as a password, where it reads the data from my card into the password box. Unfortunately, the specific card I would like to use has a "tab" character in its data. This causes the focus to shift away from the password box. I can hit shift-tab before each login, and it works, but this is a pain. I would like to disable the tab key on the lock screen

Comment: the program running before login- I have an application that can disable the tab key, and it can selectively disable this key every time a program is running. I tried to create a program that does nothing, and have it run every time the login screen is active. However, applications start after you log in, so this does not work